# how to group rows in an unique row for unique column values?

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose the next data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c('A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A2', 'A2', 'A3'), 
                 b=c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'), c=rep(1, 6))
```

I am trying to group based on unique values in `a` column such that expected data frame could look like this:

```
# a    b        c   
# A1   [a,b,c]  1
# A2   [d,e]    1
# A3   [f]      1
```

How could I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could group by 'a', 'c', `summarise` the `unique` elements to 'b' in a string

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(a, c) %>% 
   summarise(b = sprintf('[%s]', toString(unique(b))), .groups = 'drop') %>%
   select(names(df))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  a     b             c
#  <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
#1 A1    [a, b, c]     1
#2 A2    [d, e]        1
#3 A3    [f]           1
```

---

Or if the 'c' values are also changing, use `across`

```
df %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ sprintf('[%s]', 
       toString(unique(.)))), .groups = 'drop')
```

Or if we need a `list`

```
df %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ list(unique(.))
         
    ), .groups = 'drop')
```

---

Or using `glue`

```
df %>%
   group_by(a, c) %>%
   summarise(b = glue::glue('[{toString(unique(b))}]'), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  a         c b        
#* <chr> <dbl> <glue>   
#1 A1        1 [a, b, c]
#2 A2        1 [d, e]   
#3 A3        1 [f]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `aggregate` like below

```
> aggregate(. ~ a, df, unique)
   a       b c
1 A1 a, b, c 1
2 A2    d, e 1
3 A3       f 1
```

Answer (score 2):

one possible solution is this (as c is a constante maybe there is something more to your question):

```
# dummy data
df <- data.frame(a=c('A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A2', 'A2', 'A3'), 
             b=c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'), c=rep(1, 6))

# using paste with the collapse argument
df %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(a, c) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(x = paste(b, collapse = ", ")) %>% 
  # you could paste again with the brakets if you like 
  # always better to ungroup grouped data
  dplyr::ungroup()

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  a         c x      
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>  
1 A1        1 a, b, c
2 A2        1 d, e   
3 A3        1 f
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  nest(b = b) %>% 
  mutate(b = map_chr(b, ~ paste(pull(., b), collapse = ",")))
```

Or you can `pivot_wider`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(name = "b") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = b, values_fn = toString)
```